# Am I abusing toString()?

Tags: java, combobox, tostring

Javadoc for `Object.toString()` says:

> Returns a string representation of the object. In general, the
>   `toString` method returns a string that "textually represents" this
>   object. The result should be a concise but informative representation
>   that is easy for a person to read. It is recommended that all
>   subclasses override this method.  The toString method for class Object
>   returns a string consisting of the name of the class of which the
>   object is an instance, the at-sign character `'@'`, and the unsigned
>   hexadecimal representation of the hash code of the object. In other
>   words, this method returns a string equal to the value of:
>
> `getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())`

Therefore, I am questioning myself if I'm abusing this when I am overriding `toString()` of a class `Foo` just so that a ComboBox control (doesn't matter it's JavaFX or Swing control) can render a list of `Foo` correctly without me doing anything explicit in the ComboBox.

```
class Foo {
    private String name;
    public final String getName() { return name; }
    public final void setName(String n) { name = n; }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }
}

List<Foo> foos = getFoos(); // Get list of Foos from somewhere
ComboBox comboBox = ....; // Some ComboBox control
comboBox.addItems(foos); // Add the list to the ComboBox
```

The default implementation of `toString()` that most IDE generates are JSON representation of the class. I am suspecting this allows easy serialization/deserialization of class objects. Although I do not need to serialize or deserialize through this method, but I am definitely breaking this possibility by overriding like this.

### Edit

I've read the comments of many people, as well as the answer given by VGR. I can see that the general consensus is that there is no hard and fast rule on this. I see that it is generally agreed that `toString()` is better left for debugging purposes.

The biggest reason why I am doing this "hack" is because I have `ComboBox` in quite a number of different places. Of course the indisputably correct and clean way is to use a "renderer" to do this job, but it is causing a significant amount of code duplication.

I will mull over this for a few days before I decide which is the best way to do it. Thanks a lot for the bunch of comments and answer.

Comment: It's a matter of opinion, and based on my experience, it's divided. There are some reasons why using `toString` for presentation information might be a good idea (`JList` or example provides keyboard highlighting of elements based on the result of `toString`) - to me, that's just bad design. In Swing and JavaFX you have decorators/renderers which you should use to determine how a given object should be displayed in a given context. This means that in a `JList` it can look different from when it's displayed in a `JComboBox`, so on and so forth - but that's just my opinion

Comment: Short answer no it's why it's overridable. For a more complex multi-field object you might even use it to generate a concatenated string of some sort for debugging purposes.

Comment: IMHO - leave `toString` for debugging, use the GUI API to provide presentation based on the context you are trying to display it in. Yes, it might require some additional coding to get setup, but once you're up and running, it's pretty easy (and flexible)

Comment: What you need to consider is whether or not by overriding the default you will cause problems to the consumers of Foo. If at all in doubt then don't.

Comment: And looking at the code you have a Public getName() method why not use it.

Comment: Or create an interface with your own `toPrettyRenderedString()` and use that method instead.

Comment: Don't be lazy and use custom renderer (as suggested by MadProgrammer). There are there just for that purpose.

Answer (score 0):

For Swing, you definitely need to override the `toString` method of *some* class.  That’s how Swing model objects work.  (Do not use cell renderers to convert a value to String;  that will break accessibility, keyboard navigation, and built-in sorting of JTables.)

Usually you’d want to separate your display logic from your data, such as by creating a wrapper class, but since you are just returning the raw value of a property (as opposed to formatting it or concatenating it with other information), what you’re doing is fine.

JavaFX is another matter:  Controls use cell factory callback objects to determine what text appears in a cell, so a data class probably should not override `toString` with a display value in a JavaFX application.

I’m not familiar with IDEs’ auto-generated toString methods, but converting an object to JSON in a toString method is a horrible idea in my opinion.  Swing model objects should have a toString method that returns a human-readable form of the object;  most other classes should return a one-line string with a summary of the object’s state (which does not have to be every property in the object), like `getClass().getName() + "[" + getName() + "]"`.

In summary, you are not abusing toString.  For Swing, you’re doing the right thing.  For JavaFX, it’s better to return a string useful for debugging.

Comment: Actually, my actual environment is JavaFX. I did this "hack" because I am repeating the same cell factory callback code many times, as I have many Views which need to render a list of `Foo`s as `ComboBox`.

Comment: Typically, you’ll want to create a TableCell subclass, to make repeated setting of cell factories painless, since they can be specified as one-line lambdas:  `control.setCellFactory(c -> new FooCell());`